# Flipping binary numbers using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a project that the user enters an odd binary number ex: 10101 and I am supposed to have a recursive method that will flip the 1's and 0's ex: 101 = 010. For some reason my code is getting rid of the leading zero making the number an even number which crashes the program. Any and all help is appreciated, below is my Recursive class that is supposed to do the work of flipping the binary digits.

```
public class Recursive2 {
       // int digit;
    String temp;

    public Recursive2(int d){
        //digit = d;
        temp = recursive(Integer.toString(d));

        //System.out.print(recursive(temp));
    }

    public String toString(){
       return temp;
    }


    public String recursive(String a){
        String tempStr = "";
        if(a.length() % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println("Even number");
            return "";
        }
        else if(a.length() == 1){
            if(a.equals("1")){
                tempStr = "0";
               // tempStr += d;

            }
            else if(a.equals("0")){
                tempStr= "1";


            }
            //System.out.println("Flipped d to" + tempStr);
        }

        else{           
            tempStr += new Recursive2(Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0,1))).toString();
            tempStr += new Recursive2(Integer.parseInt(a.substring(1, a.length() - 1))).toString();
            tempStr += new Recursive2(Integer.parseInt(a.substring(a.length()-1, a.length()))).toString();


     }   

        return tempStr;
    }
```

Here is my main class that tests the recursion.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String num;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a Binary number with an odd amount of digits: ");
    num = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(num);
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num);
    System.out.println(num2);
    Recursive2 test = new Recursive2(num2);
    System.out.println(test);


}
```

Comment: So when you say "odd binary number" you mean an odd number of bits?

Answer (score 0):

You made several mistakes:

- Deciding if the number is odd or even should be done *before* calling recursive method. Currently, your code will stop after at most one invocation, because you check the number of bits.
- There is no need to parse `int` and making it `String` again. The entire process can be done entirely with strings.
- Constructing the result should consist of appending the result of recursive invocation without the last bit to the string representing the inverse of the last bit.
- The base case should be a situation when the string is empty, not when the string has exactly one digit.

Fixing these mistakes will produce a correct implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The current algorithm is beyond repair.

Here's a recursive algorithm that's very simple and that will work:

- if the string is empty, return it
- if the first char is 0, `return "1" + recurse(s.substring(1))`
- otherwise (the first char is 1), `return "0" + recurse(s.substring(1))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are converting to integer values, which will throw away leading zeros. Just deal with strings:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String num;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a Binary number with an odd amount of digits: ");
    num = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(num);
    String flipped;
    if (num.length() % 2 == 0) {
        flipped = "Even number";
    else {
        flipped = Recursive2.recursive(num);
    }
    System.out.println(flipped);
}
```

And the `Recursive2` class can just have `static` methods:

```
public class Recursive2 {
    private static String flip(char c) {
        if (c == '0') return "1";
        return "0"; // assumes characters are all 0 or 1
    }
    public static String recursive(String a) {
        STring tempStr;
        if (a.length() == 0) {
            tempStr = "";
        } else {
            tempStr = flip(a.charAt(0)) + recursive(a.substring(1));
        }
        return tempStr;
    }
}
```

You might want to throw an exception if you detect a character other than `0` or `1`.

EDIT: Based on your comment, the recursive method can be written as:

```
public static String recursive(String a) {
    String tempStr = flip(a.charAt(0));
    final int len = a.length();
    if (len > 1) {
        tempStr += recursive(a.substring(1, len - 1)) + flip(a.charAt(len - 1));
    }
    return tempStr;
}
```

This assumes that the argument is an odd-length string. That check should be done outside the recursive method, since if it is true once, it is true at every subsequent recursion.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to pass an integer and the recursive method is supposed to remove the first and last bit then send it through the recursive method again until the length is 1.

Comment: @Chris - Ah. In that case, you can convert it to a `String` and add a 0 at the start if it is even length. Then use the procedure I described. If you really have to chop off both ends at the same time, just change the base case to test for length 1. I'd still put the check for even length input in `main()`. I'll update my answer to show how I'd do this.

Answer (score 0):

Leading zeros are ignored because you're converting the input binary number to integer. For an integer leading zeros don't mean anything. You should be working with `String` only.

Also `Integer.parseInt(num);` would assume that you want to parse a decimal number not binary. If you do want to parse a binary number then you'll have to use another overloaded method [Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

However as I said, because of the leading zeros you should work only with the Strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to instead, remove one digit from the String that the user has imputed, and convert it (from the 1 to 0 vise versa), then use sub-string as the pass for the recursive function with one less.

Hint-> the base case would be a.length() == 0;   because if you remove one digit of the string you will eventually have the length be 0.

Good Luck!

Comment: Look again. OP's method calls itself in the last `else` branch.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(i)` converts the `String` to its `Integer` value.

However the `Integer` value of `010` is `10`, leading `0's` are dropped.

Work with the input as a `String` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder` to avoid creating new `String` or you can use `char` array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int no = 1234; // some no
    String in = Integer.toBinaryString(no);
    System.out.println("Original " + in);
    System.out.println("Flipped  " + flipBits(in));
}

public static String flipBits(String in) {
    if (in.length() % 2 == 0)
        return "even length";
    return new String(flipBits(in.toCharArray(), in.length() - 1));
}

private static char[] flipBits(char[] ch, int index) {
    if (index < 0) {
        return ch;
    } else {
        ch[index] = Character.forDigit(49 - ch[index], 2); //flip
        return flipBits(ch, index - 1);
    }
}
```

output

```
Original 10011010010
Flipped  01100101101
```